# Intersection of prime ideals of ring of ALL algebraic integers lying over a particular prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

At first sight, my question seems quite arbitrary. I hope it is nevertheless interesting. Actually I wanted to know more about non-Noetherian domains having Krull dimension one and I was therefore searching for examples. One example of such a ring is the integral closure $A$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ in some algebraic closure $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$.

I already know that every non-zero prime ideal of $A$ contracts to a non-zero prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ and that, given a prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$, there are in general infinitely many prime ideals $M \subseteq A$ such that $M \cap \mathbb{Z} = (p)$. Let $V(p)$ denote the set of all such prime ideals of $A$.

Now to my actual question: Given some $Q \in V(p)$, can it happen that $\bigcap_{M \in V(p) \setminus \{Q\}} M \subseteq Q$, or is this never the case?

This would solve a problem I have been thinking about for quite a while.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Isn't $ \bigcap_{M \in V(p) \setminus \{Q\}} M $ just $pA$ ? Or do you have a concrete example where the inclusion is strict ?  In fact, I have the feeling that you can always find two prime ideals $M,M'$ lying above $p$ such that $M\cap M'=pA$...but I might be wrong...

Comment: That was also a question I was asking myself, but I also do not know... Do you have an example where equality holds?

Comment: Only taking $M,M'$ as you did will not work, since  $M \cap M' = pA \subseteq Q$ would imply that either $M$ or $M'$ would be in $Q$ because it is prime.